# Array Try Catch can't recognize array length in if statement

Tags: java, arrays, variables

I had a program that has the user enter up to 5 numbers into an array then it decides what the minimum value is out of those numbers. I tried adding a try catch to it but it won't recognize the i in the [].

I've tried initializing it in the if statement but it didn't work.

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class Main {

      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
         double numbers[] = new double[5];

         boolean done = false;
         java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.println("\tFind the min value ");
         System.out.println();

         while(!done)
     {
      try
      {
                System.out.println("Enter 5 double numbers:");

                for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)

                numbers[i] = sc.nextDouble();
                System.out.println();

                if (numbers[i] < 0) throw new InputMismatchException();
                done = true;
      }
              catch(InputMismatchException e)
              {
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Error, enter a number greater than 0");
                sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("");
              }
         }
           System.out.println("The min value is " +min(numbers)+ ".");
           System.out.println();
      }
        public static double min(double[] array) 
        {
          double min = array[0];

          for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)

          if (array[i] < min)
          min = array[i];
          return min;
     }
    }
```

Just want the try catch to catch any numbers entered that are less than 0

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't recognize the i"?

Comment: Oh, because your for-loop is only a single line?

Comment: You must use `{` and `}` in `for` loops when you need more than 1 line

Comment: As @ManishPatel didn't refer to this, I'm going to say this. There is something called a `scope` in Java. Look here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you missed `{` and `}` in your loop condition.

Try this code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     double numbers[] = new double[5];

     boolean done = false;
     java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.println("\tFind the min value ");
     System.out.println();

     while(!done) {
         try {
            System.out.println("Enter 5 double numbers:");

            for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                numbers[i] = sc.nextDouble();
                System.out.println();

                if (numbers[i] < 0) throw new InputMismatchException();
                done = true;
            }
         } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
              System.out.println("");
              System.out.println("Error, enter a number greater than 0");
              sc.nextLine();
              System.out.println("");
         }
     }
     System.out.println("The min value is " +min(numbers)+ ".");
     System.out.println();
  }

  public static double min(double[] array) {
      double min = array[0];

      for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
         if (array[i] < min)
         min = array[i];
      }

      return min;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error is that you are using a for loop without brackets. This means that the `i` is recognized only by the line after the loop declaration and not the lines after. So, instead of this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
```

Do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    //Do your loop here. "i" will be recognized.
}
```